# Is it possible to change all Guava API with the Java 8 API?

Tags: java, api, java-8, sonarqube, guava

My project just ran sonar scan, and I found 1 reported case, which is:

> Sonar suggest use Java 8 API instead of Guava API.

In some cases, I can change the API, but I found some of the cases, where I cannot find the corresponding Java 8 substitution for Guava.

For example:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

Optional<String> proxyHost;
this.proxyHost = checkNotNull(proxyHost, "proxyHost is required")
                .orNull(); // this line will having compilation error orNull method undefined.
```

I am trying to find a replacement in Java 8 API to replace the Guava `checkNotNull`, but it looks like Java 8 does not have it. And this is just one of the examples.

I cannot find any replacement for the following snippet as well:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables.tryFind;
import com.google.common.base.Suppliers;
```

and so on.

Can I find the Java 8 replacement API for this somewhere? or I should mask this case as false positive in the Sonar scan?

Comment: As you are using Optional you can do like `proxyHost.orElse(null)` or `proxyHost.orElseThrow(...)`

Answer (score 2):

The Java 8 API which specifically can be used instead of `Preconditions.checkNotNull(T)` is `Objects.requireNonNull(T)`. However, in your case you have an `Optional` instance, so probably you don't want to check that your variable is `null`, but that it is non-empty. This can be done with `Optional.orElseThrow` as follows:

```
this.proxyHost = proxyHost.orElseThrow(() -> new SomeExceptionClass("proxyHost is required"));
```

The Guava documentation for the `Iterables` class specifies that in many cases where `Iterables` is used, you can use Java 8 `Stream`s instead.

For the `Suppliers` class I don't known direct equivalents for Java 8 `Supplier` instances.

Answer (score -1):

You can write like this
For throwing an error, you can use as below.

**`proxyHost.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("proxyHost is required"));`**

Or setting default you can try with

**`String result=proxyHost.isPresent()?proxyHost.get():"proxyHost is required";`**

Comment: `checkNotNull`'s second argument is the error message, not the default to use instead.

Comment: See [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) for how to call that API. Code that compiles makes for a better answer.

Comment: @Joe I am just giving him hint, i had added exact code with Exception.